# Html translation confusion

Tags: .net, asp.net, html

I have `&` embedded in a sentence on my page comes from the database , when i get it i have `&amp;` instead ,how to get

`&` as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` means "Start an entity" in HTML and it sounds like it is being error corrected at some point.

You need to decode the HTML, or at least run it though a library for decoding entities.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `<%: %>` construct (in `.NET 4`):

```
<%: "This & that" %>
```

Or use [`HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) for this:

```
<%= Server.HtmlEncode("This & that") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using MVC use the <%= tag to write it out rather than <%:

You also might need to decode the HTML. Server.HtmlDecode()

Note this also works the other way round with Server.HtmlEncode()

Answer (score 1):

You should be extremely careful about taking stuff out of your database and sending it directly, unencoded, to an HTML page.   If what's in the database was generated totally by you, and is known to be safe HTML then you should be OK.  But if any of it comes from user input (even in the distant past), then you should think hard before you trust it.